# Big data analysis on CDR (call details record). Help :D

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, pentaho, etl, telecommunication

I have been assigned an analysis project on the internal call records of a call center. This being my first experience with big data analysis, can someone guide me on how to go about this project? Where to begin and the tools to be used? Pentaho, Etl tools,Hadoop. Suggestions?

Comment: What kind of analysis do you intend to do ?, Do you have access to the data ?

Answer (score 1):

Tips

- Understanding the data
- Identify what kind of insights you want to gather i.e. what questions do you want to ask?
- Is it really BigData [(Use 4 V's](http://www.sas.com/en_us/insights/big-data/what-is-big-data.html) to figure this out) or something that tools like R can help you with?

Once you understood the above, you will know how to proceed